# I am getting error in workbox PrecacheController.install

Tags: workbox

Installation of the service-worker failed.

I got this error after running the code on another machine.

> Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined
>   at PrecacheController.install (PrecacheController.mjs:97)

This happens after

```
const cache = await caches.open(this._cacheName);
```

cacheName at that point is 'workbox-precache-v2-https://localhost:5001/', which seems valid.

There indeed is no cache yet, as expected on a first run.

[image]

Service-worker.js

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js');

if (workbox) {
    //the following line is a placeholder
    workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);

    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
        new RegExp('https://localhost:44365/api/.*'),
        new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst());


    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
        /\.js$/,
        new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst());
} else {
    console.log(`Boo! Workbox didn't load `);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ho my ...

Chrome is managed by my organisation and they have set SyncDisabled to true.

**EDIT:**
And running chrome as administrator to bypass the limitation.